# Оформление. Назойливое выделение группы вопросов

Tags: обсуждение

Решил вынести в обсуждение, т.к. ответом администрации не удовлетворен.

Открыта страница *Вопросы*, количество *Конкурсных*  выделяется из общего фона (см. картинку). Мелочь? Не просто выделяется - сразу притягивает внимание,  **заставляет терять на него время**.

Такое форматирование нужно и приветствуется для той информации, которая восстребована пользователем. Но для чего информацию бросать в глаза ВСЕМ?

На этот вопрос получено разъяснение администрации:

> Это желательное поведение, которое заложено в систему с целью, как вы
>   совершенно верно заметили, выделения группы вопросов в общем потоке.
>   Система конкурсов предназначена для вопросов, на которые сообщество
>   уделило слишком мало внимания, по мнению одного из участников. Выделяя
>   их, система гарантирует восполнить недостаток внимания.

```
---------
```

> Это желательное поведение, которое заложено в систему с целью...

Согласен: никак не удается уговорить собственный мозг, что это для него спам )

С чем не согласен.

> Выделяя их, система гарантирует восполнить недостаток внимания

Откуда гарантии? Да, привлекает внимание, но не восполняет недостаток. А вот раздражения пользователю добавляет. Проверено, даю гарантию )

> ...для вопросов, на которые сообщество уделило слишком мало внимания,
>   по мнению одного из участников

Получается, что один участник решает, нужно ли привлечь внимание ВСЕХ посетителей?

Администрация упускает из виду: не все интересуются конкурсами; не всем итересен рейтинг, который можно повысить, помогая в конкурсных вопросах; не все разбираются в языках, которые обсуждаются в конкурсной закладке.

Так зачем принуждать всех обращать внимание на то, что интересно единицам (десяткам, сотням...- не всем)?

Возможно, "переместить с центра внимания"? Сделать менее "притягательно-назойливым"?

> К сожалению, запрос убрать выделение не будет реализован.

Но почитать, что об этом думают другие, можно, надеюсь. Может, я один такой на белом свете? :)
[image: яркое_пятно]

Comment: Вот если бы оно ещё мигало и издавало звуки ...

Comment: @alexolut, и в `<marquee>` завернуть

Comment: >>Вот если бы оно ещё мигало и издавало звуки - я бы повесился :)

Comment: Ну, если вас сильно раздражает, это ж легко убрать при помощи юзерскрипта.

Comment: Это можно убрать с помощью какого-нибудь адблока.

Answer (score 8):

Я буду отвечать на поступившие вопросы в обратном порядке, потому что ответы связаны именно в таком.

> Но почитать, что об этом думают другие, можно, надеюсь.

Конечно. Я ничего не имею против такого обозначения.

Оно яркое, чтобы **привлекать внимание**, и оно привлекло достаточно **вашего внимания**, чтобы довести вас до стадии раздражения и задать этот вопрос. Значит, свою задачу оформление решает.

Правда, чем вас это раздражает, я не знаю: в моём понимании эта "визуальная подсказка" уже обрела определённый смысл и я воспринимаю её, как осмысленную часть интерфейса. Я понимаю её роль, умею ею пользоваться, и при случае могу быстро найти. А те, кто о её роли ещё не понимают, её всё равно заметят и осмотрят. Эти характеристики делают эту деталь в моих глазах *качественным элементом графического интерфейса пользователя* и вообще визуального языка, используемого StackExchange.

> не все интересуются конкурсами; не всем итересен рейтинг, который можно повысить, помогая в конкурсных вопросах

Меня тоже не слишком парит рейтинг. Но меня парит то, что он означает: польза от нахождения ответов на практические вопросы. Польза есть как от тех, кто вопросы формулирует, так и от тех, кто находит ответы.

Я понимаю, для чего придумана система и играю по её правилам, хотя и осознаю, что *правила дырявые* и показатель репутации вообще-то мало что означает: но мне наплевать. Меня волнует только то, сколько собственного опыта я смог передать широкой общественности + сколько приобрёл сам в результате поисков. Для меня это взаимовыгодный обмен. А репутация приклеена где-то сбоку и болтается рядом.

Поэтому конкурсы для меня ничего толком не означают. Пару раз я даже замечал их использование в роли "режима бога" для вопросов, которым грозило закрытие: уже висело 4/5 закрывашек, а повесить пятую и закрыть вопрос не даёт конкурс. Нечестно? Ну, люди расстаются с репутацией за это, зная, что не получат её обратно, даже если желаемый эффект не будет достигнут.

Тех, кому рейтинг неинтересен, бесит огромное число напоминаний об этом рейтинге *по всему интерфейсу*, начиная с верхней панели? Некоторых — возможно, но вас, судя по приведённому аргументу, нет.

> не все разбираются в языках, которые обсуждаются в конкурсной закладке

...не все разбираются в языках, которые обсуждаются и на главной странице тоже.

А список конкурсных вопросов со временем меняется. Поскольку конкурс можно теоретически назначить на любой (активный) вопрос, теоретический охват аудитории 100%: для любого участника в случайно взятый момент времени есть ненулевая вероятность, что в конкурсных вопросах окажется вопрос, на который он в состоянии ответить.

> Получается, что один участник решает, нужно ли привлечь внимание ВСЕХ посетителей?

*Совершенно верно*, но он платит за эту возможность очками, набранными в результате полезного вклада в сообщество. Он честно (с точки зрения системы) заслужил такую возможность.

> Откуда гарантии? Да, привлекает внимание, но не восполняет недостаток.

А никто не может сказать, сколько внимания вопросу на самом деле *достаточно*. Спросить у разных сторон — можно услышать разные точки зрения.

Поэтому объективно это просто "привлекает больше внимания", и делает это так, чтобы вопросу досталось как можно больше — чтобы с высокой вероятностью было "достаточно".

Когда речь идёт о системах, управляемых большими массами людей, невозможно поддерживать никакой формальный инвариант: человеческий фактор может сломать что угодно. Поэтому можно говорить лишь о "повышении вероятности" и "средних случаях".

Comment: Субъективное мнение основано на субъективном восприятии. Часто ошибочно. Ответы это подтверждают. Спасибо.

Comment: >>Тех, кому рейтинг неинтересен, бесит ... Некоторых — возможно, но вас, судя по приведённому аргументу, нет. ===== 1. я не писал, что отношусь к рейтингу отрицательно; 2. он (рейтинг) не выделяется на общем фоне страницы.=== не со всеми доводами, показанными в ответах. согласен,  но - полезно, однозначно.

Answer (score 7):

**Я поставил вопросу минус**, поскольку не согласен с изложенным вами текстом.

> Открыта страница Вопросы, количество Конкурсных выделяется из общего фона...
>   Не просто выделяется - сразу притягивает внимание, заставляет терять
>   на него время.

Терять время на что, позвольте уточнить? Скользнуть взглядом по вкладке?

> Получается, что один участник решает, нужно ли привлечь внимание ВСЕХ
>   посетителей?

Верно лишь отчасти. Верная часть эта:

> один участник решает, нужно ли привлечь внимание

Кому это не интересно, игнорирует эту вкладку.

Кроме того, данное действие не бесплатное. Участник платит за это частью своей репутации.
Репутация теряется безвозвратно, а заработать ее на сайте не так-то просто.

Каждый свой вопрос сделать конкурсным у обычного участника точно не выйдет.

> Откуда гарантии? Да, привлекает внимание, но не восполняет недостаток.
>   А вот раздражения пользователю добавляет. Проверено, даю гарантию

Вы обобщаете. На сайте есть пользователи, да и чего греха таить, я к ним тоже отношусь, которым репутация на сайте важна. Думаю, что вопрос с наградой в виде дополнительной репутации может привлечь внимание таких пользователей.

Бывает такое, что писать подробное руководство или перелопачивать кучу форумов, чтобы ответить на вопрос пользователя банально лень. Дополнительная репутация за ответ на конкурсный вопрос — это дополнительный стимул приложить больше усилий для ответа.

Лично у меня никакого раздражения подобное оформление не вызывает, что лишний раз доказывает, что вы спроецировали свое мнение на остальных пользователей сайта (еще одна причина поставить минус вопросу).

Кто не разбирается в вопросе или кого не интересует рейтинг, думаю, вполне успешно игнорируют указанную вами вкладку.

Массовых жалоб на этот момент точно не было ни на основном сайте сети, ни на этом. К сожалению, всем не угодишь.

Вся суть вашей проблемы решается установкой расширением плагина для браузера, позволяющего применить к сайту собственные стили.

Например, для Chrome это [Stylish](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/stylish/fjnbnpbmkenffdnngjfgmeleoegfcffe?hl=ru).

Добавьте в него правило:

```
.bounty-indicator-tab {
    display: none;
}
```

И проблема решена.

Comment: >>Добавьте в него правило ==== Никогда там не был ), но теперь есть причина, чтобы и в этом покопаться. Спасибо.